# rm -r path : how to avoid being asked at each level?

Tags: rm

How to avoid being asked at each level if I want to delete that path?  I just want to remove everything in a path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `-I` switch if you want to be prompted only once:

```
rm -rI sampledir/
```

from `man rm`:

```
-I     prompt once before removing more than three files, or when removing recursively.
       Less intrusive than -i, while still giving protection against most mistake
```

and use `-f` for "no prompt":

```
-f, --force
       ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

so:

```
rm -rf sampledir/
```

Comment: had to use -f for no prompt

Comment: @jdl - Yes, `-f` is for no prompt, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: If I use the -I switch, it will ask "remove all arguments recursively"? Is there a way to customize this message including the foldername / directory path intending to remove?